# Get the Entry type of a KeyStore programatically

Tags: java, keystore, keytool, jks

With the keytool command, we have this kind of information:

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: myname
Creation date: 21-Aug-2011
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
...
```

In Java (programatically), how can I retrieve the "Entry type" value to know if it's a private certificate or a public? I'm using the KeyStore Java class this way:

```
File file = new File(filePath);
String password = password.toCharArray();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(format);
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(file), password);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is check if the `KeyEntry` for the given alias in the KeyStore is a PrivateKeyEntry or a TrustedCertificateEntry.

```java
char[] password = "mypassword";

ProtectionParameter passwordProtection = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password.toCharArray());

KeyEntry entry = keystore.getEntry("myname", passwordProtection);

if (entry instanceof PrivateKeyEntry) {
    // is a private key entry
}
```

Comment: when "myname" refers to trusted cert entry this code throws UnsupportedOperationException("trusted certificate entries are not password-protected"). it doesn't look a reliable solution...